# How to access API Gateway endpoint from another account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I've an API that should only be accessed from another AWS account. I've followed some AWS documentation and this is what I've done:

- Created an internal NLB in front of an ASG. All these are in a private subnet.
- Created an API Gateway that connects to the NLB using a VPC Link.
- Created a Custom Domain Name (via Route53) and set a certificate using ACM.
- The resources use `AWS_IAM` as authorisation.
- The resource policy grants the other account authorisation to the resource.
- In the authorised account, I've created an EC2 instance and associated an IAM role with full access to the API Gateway.

When I try to connect signing the requests (using [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html)), it works just fine. But the the request signing requires the AWS access key and secret key.
This doesn't sound right to me. What am I doing wrong? Is there another way of doing this without the credentials?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

When required to provide the access key and secret key, I suppose you need to install the authorising app called Postman (please check out this doc：https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-use-postman-to-call-api.html).

Also, in your step 5, I think if you want to access the api gateway endpoint from an ec2, you have to firstly create a Role within that ec2 account, and then attach the Role to that ec2, finally grant the Role with api gateway permission in your current account.